# Assign custom image to programmatically created product

Tags: magento

once guest user click on button "add to cart1", we are doing below things:

1. we are creating simple product programmatically
2. we are assigning custom image to that product.
3. Display one more pop up to Login to site by click on "login" button

once user click on "login button, we are doing below things:

1. we are creating simple product programmatically
2. we are not assigning custom image to that product.

but here we need to assign custom image to that product.

```
public function thisSimpleProductAndRedirectAction()
    {
        $originalProductId = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
        // $productNameArray = explode(" - ",$this->getRequest()->getParam("id"));
        // $originalProductId = $productNameArray[0];
        $newImagePath      = $this->getRequest()->getParam("image");
        $originalProduct   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($originalProductId);

        if ($product = $this->_createProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath)) {
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode("custom image saving"));
        }
        else{
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode("custom image not saving"));
        }

    }

 protected function _thisImage($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = "")
    {

        // code for Guest
        Mage::register('isSecureArea',true);    
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        $result = array(
            'success' => false
        );

        $login ="";
        $productId ="";
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
        }
            // echo $login['product_id'];die;
            // if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    if(isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login!="")){
                        $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
                        $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array(
                            '_secure' => true
                        ));
                        $result['success']  = true;
                        $customerId         = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                    }
                    else{
                        $customerId = "";
                    }

                    // code for guest end        

                    $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());

                    // add images

                    $images = array(
                        'thumbnail' => 'image.png', // displaying under cart page

                        'image' => 'image.png' // displaying under my design
                    );

                    foreach ($images as $imageType => $imageFileName) {
                        if ($newImagePath != "") {
                            $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
                            $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
                        } else {
                            $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
                            $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
                        }
                        //echo $path."<br>";
                        if (file_exists($path)) {
                            try {
                                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($path, $imageType, false);
                            }
                            catch (Exception $e) {
                                echo $e->getMessage();
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "Can not find image by path: `{$path}`<br/>";
                        }
                    }                  

                    $emailimage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');

                    if ($doSave)
                        $product->save();                  

                    return $product;

                    // code for guest

                }
                catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    switch ($e->getCode()) {
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_EMAIL_NOT_CONFIRMED:
                            $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('This account is not confirmed. <a href="%s">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', Mage::helper('customer')->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']));
                            break;
                        case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                            break;
                        default:
                            $message = $e->getMessage();
                    }
                    $result['error'] = $message;
                    $session->setUsername($login['username']);
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $result = "ERROR :".$e->getMesage();

        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        // code for guest end
    }
```

Comment: What error you are facing?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i dont see any errors, but i dont know why custom image is not assigning to product after click on "login" button.....

Comment: @DhirenVasoya can you please check code and help me ?

Comment: Have you check in admin, using your code assign image to product and show in admin?

Comment: yes, i checked in admin, its not displaying custom image, means its not displaying image in this path : `custom_product_preview/quote/'` but displaying image in this path : `example/amasty`]

Comment: debug your code, I think you need to verify path which is set during upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your code :

```
if ($newImagePath != "") 
{   
    $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
    $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
} 
else 
{    
    $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
    $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
}
```

with this code :

```
$path = '';
if ($newImagePath != "") 
    {   
        $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview/quote/';
        $path = $dir . $newImagePath;
    } 
    else 
    {    
        $dir  = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'example/amasty/';
        $path = $dir . $imageFileName;
    }
```